# custom redirect to home page not working in magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, url-rewrite, cms

what iam trying to achieve is : to redirect a cms page to home page;
the cms page is accessible by domain.com/home
what i need is to redirect to domain/

i had already created a custom url rewrite rule from magento admin

```
ID Path :home(this is the url key of the cms page & this page is accessible via domain/home)
Request Path :domain/home 
Target Path : domain
Redirect : Permanent 301
```

But no luck ! im still getting the same cms page (No redirection ) tried clearing cache but still the same result.

Answer (score 3):

**Magento,** rewrite manage work  whenever ***Request Path & Target without base url.***

*Why, you did tried with  htaccess  301 redirection.*

It is `every good idea use htaccess 301` if you using **Apache** as **web server**

```
# Permanent URL redirect - generated by 
Redirect 301 http://domain.com/home http://domain.com/
```

---

***Or,you can use magento event observer.***

In magento,when a *Cms is call*,then an event [*`cms_page_render`*](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php#L107)  is fire *`before  render layout`*.

And on  this event using **magento 301 redirection**

(`Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl(),301)->sendResponse()`)

and on basic of page identifier match `$observer->getEvent()->getPage()->getIdentifier()=='home'`

**You can redirect to domain.com/home page  to domain.com/**

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
......
  <global>
    <events>
      <cms_page_render> 
        <observers>
          <slash_home_to_domain>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>ModuleNameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>Home301redirect</method>
          </slash_home_to_domain>
        </observers>
      </cms_page_render>     
    </events>
  </global>
.....
</config>
```

**Observer code:**

> ```
> <?php
> class ModuleNameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer
> {
>
>     public function Home301redirect($observer)
>     {
>       $cmspage = $observer->getEvent();
>       /* Condition match and redirect to home */
>       if($cmspage->getIdentifier()=='home'):
>   Mage::app()->getResponse()
>       ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl(), 301)
>       ->sendResponse();
>       exit();
>       endif;
>       return;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I tried redirection with .htacces, But its not working, Iam not an expert in doing these stuff like observer :(. But why the redirection is not working as i mentioned !!!

Comment: May ur server htaccess now allow magento htaccess

Answer (score 0):

> Request Path :domain/home
>   Target Path : domain

I think the issue come from "domain" (other Magento rewrite URLs doesn't mention it)

Try with this:

```
Request Path: home  
Target Path: /
```

Let us know if it works,

Comment: I tried this . But not Redirecting

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue. However it worked when I used this combination:

> Request Path: **home** 
> Target Path: **../**

The key points to the above are that the Request Path should not have a preceding forward slash, and the Target Path needs the preceding two dots. This is the only combination that worked on my site.